# JOIN query order in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, join

Are there any best practices regarding the order of nested JOINs in MySQL queries?

Any rules of thumb to follow for maximal performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [this artticle on Nested Join Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/nested-join-optimization.html), I think it may be what you're looking for. Hope this helps!